# Connection to Derby Database 10.11.1.1 being refused with ij tool working java code

Tags: java, sql, derby

Presently I have a Derby database... Version 10.11.1.1 Created via a Java app which is functional only when communicated to by the java app running arbitrary queries. Maven dependency as follows:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.11.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

When I try to use the ij tool or any other third-party applications:

```
i.e. connect 'jdbc:derby:/home/username/dev/db-agents/TESTDB';
```

is unable to do so, complaining about the wrong version is being used, Like as follows:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database at /home/username/dev/db-agents/TESTDB has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.11.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: ERROR XSLAN: Database at /home/username/dev/db-agents/TESTDB has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.11.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.readControlFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.bootLogFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.setRawStoreFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
```

I can't understand why I can connect from the Java app and nothing else? Is there something in particular I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ij session is using an older version of Derby.

This is controlled by the CLASSPATH that is set when you run ij.

Look closely at the script or command you are using to start ij, to see which version of Derby it is running.

Then adjust the CLASSPATH that you use when you [run ij](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/tools/ttoolsij11815.html) so that it uses Derby 10.11, which is the version your Java app is using.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of the ij tool to match up with versions though : http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.11.1.1.cgi

Comment: It's still possible for you to have other versions of Derby on your system, and those might be the ones your ij session is using. Copies of Derby come packaged with JDKs, IDEs, Application Servers, and many other tools. Did you carefully examine your CLASSPATH?

Comment: Excuse me for not knowing how exactly to point it to 10.11.1.1 ? I have presently the derby-10.11.11.1/bin obviously in my PATH (Linux) and that's what the ij tool is referring to. It appears when the ij tool is run it responds with 10.8 ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be rude. The Derby 10.8 is probably the one that was bundled with a copy of JDK 1.7 on your machine, and is in $JAVA_HOME/db. So do: "export CLASSPATH=/path/to/derby/db-derby-10.11.11.1/lib/derbyrun.jar" and see if then ij runs the 10.11 version of Derby.